# Enable Infopath button

Tags: database, windows, sharepoint, ms-office, infopath

Ok so am fairly new to SharePoint and InfoPath but here is the thing. I have made this form in InfoPath. Section A gets data from a SharePoint library, Section B get data from another SharePoint library but that data is dependent on the data in Section A. Section C gets data from another different library but the data is also dependent on whats in Section A. So now I want the 'Show' button I have circled to be disable and enabled only when the queried record exists in the Library of Section C.
[InfoPath Form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQWfp.png)

Answer (score 0):

On the Button you want disabled, create a Formatting Rule to disable that control with a condition of one of your fields being empty or some value it wouldnt be until the other section is showing that data.